# How to export the contents of a column into a Flat file using SSIS package

Tags: xml, ssis

I have a column from a table which has xml content in it such that each row of that column can be a sperate xml file if copied and pasted on a text file and saved as xml file.

I am trying to use the inbuilt features of the SSIS to extract each column value and create a flat file out of it and just save it as an XML extension.

I think I can do it through the script task and develop a code to do it but I was wondering if there is a more direct way in SSIS to do it.

Ex:

select log
from XYZ_Table

I want to save every log value into a flat file and rename it to .xml

Is this possible?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: We've used a simple script task to accomplish something similar.  Our solution was basically return the result set, then with a for-each loop pass FilePath, FileName and FileData to c# script task and use file.WriteAllText().  You'd be looking at row by row processing, but it's doable and worked for us.  Outside of that if you wanted to use a data-flow with a flatfile destination I'm sure its possible, we just used the script task route as hooking it up and using it seemed easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the file path in another column within the Data Flow, you can use an [Export Column Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/export-column-transformation?view=sql-server-2017) to create an XML file for each row.  However if the file path is not contained in one of the columns in the Data Flow, you can either add a derived Column that contains an expression or use a Script Component to add a column with a unique file path/name for each XML file.  In order to have the XML written to a file, it will need to be stored as using either the `DT_TEXT` or `DT_NTEXT` data type, and if you store this as Unicode, make sure that the `Write Byte-Order` option is checked on the Export Column component.